# zxing QR scanner not working only lollipop 5.1 version

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have done the implementation of QR scanner in android application. It does work in 6.0 and some other os version but it is not working in lollipop 5.1 version getting crashed when I clicked QR scanner not getting the handle intent.

Code:

```
     public  void aadahrScan() {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

     @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCodeTools, int resultCodeTools, Intent intentTools) {
            if (requestCodeTools == 0 && intentTools != null) {
                requestCodeTools(resultCodeTools, intentTools);
            }
        }

Error:



  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.boon.inthree, PID: 6034
                                                                    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN }
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1799)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1508)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3829)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:30)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:146)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:937)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1047)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:959)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:948)
                                                                        at com.boon.inthree.PersonalInformation.aadahrScan(PersonalInformation.java:263)
                                                                        at com.boon.inthree.PersonalInformation$4.onClick(PersonalInformation.java:251)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:71
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashClass"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>



    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProductActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProductDeteils"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Checkout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProCheckout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".QuickActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FilterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SyncActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DashOrderReview"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Thankyou"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ConformCheckout"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RetailereKyc"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

        </activity>
```

I added the manifest file also I gave all the permission which is need to access the camera

Please solve this problem anyone Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably, the app is not installed.

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: I added the manifest file please check it

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I put this already in manifest file, but it is not working again back to same screen.

Comment: No, If i put this intent filter in manifest file, I don't get the logcat error but  scanner is not working.